# c# Functions, Invalid token 'bool' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#

I am new to using functions in c# and I have tried to make a function that returns either true if a number is division le by 100 and false if it is not and the function does not seem to be working, can someone point me in the right direction please. It is saying the bool part is incorrect. Here is some code that I have tried:

```
namespace Divide_By_100
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public void bool Divisible (int number)
        {
            if (number % 100 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message: Invalid token 'bool' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: A method can only have a single return type so remove the word `void` to fix your syntax error.

Comment: You can have only one return type per function. You have both `void` and `bool` which is incorrect. Just have `bool`.

Comment: Its the void part. voids does not return anything remove void

Comment: Any time you ask about an error message always remember to include the error message.

Comment: I think it would have been helpful to you to address *why* you think you need `void` in the first place. From the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void): "When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the method doesn't return a value"

Comment: The '(number % 100 == 0)' returns bool itself, so there is no need to use if () {} then {} - replace all function body with 'return (number % 100 == 0);'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method cannot have two return types, like `void` and `bool`. Remove the `void` keyword from the method signature.

```
namespace Divide_By_100
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public bool Divisible (int number)
        {
            if (number % 100 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to return two types -  `(int,bool) MyFun(int v){ return (42, true);}`...

Comment: Your example also has one return type which is (int, bool)